# Github pages won't load image but vs code will

Tags: html, image, github

So i have a github page and it's not loading the background img, whereas the exact same code is working in vscode.

```
.banner{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.75), rgba(0,0,0,0.75)),url(/styles/background.png);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}
```

My tree:

- Styles

  - background.png
  - styles.css

I've tried everything from different urls to changing its destination but i cannot fix it no matter what

Comment: `/styles/background.png` — presumably the root of your local server and the root of the Github Pages server don't map on to the same locations relative to the heirachy of your website. So you get a 404 error.

Comment: `Styles` and `styles` are different on most systems too.